# Props change parent if object Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My question it's more a search for explanation.

I have two components, father and child.

**Father**:

```
<template>
    <Child :data="testData" />
        {{testData}} //for print data in father
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       name: "Father",
       data() {
          return {
             testData: {name: "hello"}
          }
       }
    }
 </script>
```

And then My Child

```
<template>
   <input v-model="data.name" />
</template>
<script>
   export default {
       name: "Child",
         props: ["data"]
        }
   }
</script>
```

As documentation say in this section:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

I expected that it will return error, but no, it's work, if I try to change input the father component show the correct new value, without console error.

So I have tested with simple string for data instead of object in father like:

**Father** :

```
<template>
    <Child :data="testData" />
        {{testData}} //for print data in father
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       name: "Father",
       data() {
          return {
             testData: "hello"
          }
       }
    }
 </script>
```

**Child** :

```
<template>
   <input v-model="data" />
</template>
<script>
   export default {
       name: "Child",
         props: ["data"]
        }
   }
</script>
```

And in this case I will get the correct error:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
> overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
> data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
> mutated: "data"
>
> found in

Yes I know that in JS the object are different and "magic", but I expected that Vuejs not allowed this.

Is this desired/due(for JS specifics) behavior?

Thankyou.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, is it an explanation on *why* Vue uses props that are only one way?

Comment: yes, I'm asking for explanation why the props of vue, which should be only one way, with objects are not.

Comment: What do you mean objects are not one way? They are, hence the error you received. (Yes, it still modifies it but this is bad practice when working with Vue)

Comment: No, If i use object I don't receive error. This is my question, why I don't receive error with object, object as {name: "hello"}

Comment: Excuse me pal, I've mis-read the question. I'll go mess around with this and see what I can find out for you as I'm not entirely sure myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both exemples, your prop value is an object, or a *link* to an object (and its attributes/properties).

When you use `v-model="data.name"`, you are not *changing the prop*, you are following the *link*, accessing the object, and only changing one of its attributes.
Can't say if this is bad practice, but it works great for me.

In the second exemple, the `v-model="data"` would actually *change the link* to another object, not only the prop internals.
This results in an error.

This thread can also help: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/pass-object-via-props-reference-vs-emit-value-best-practices/45683/5

Comment: thankyou.
it make sense.
I also have found this https://forum.vuejs.org/t/pass-object-via-props-reference-vs-emit-value-best-practices/45683/5
Add link to your answer for more clarity then i will accept your answer! thankyou